# Image in a custom List Android

Tags: android, image, list, adapter

I have created a custom adapter to display a list, there is an image that is displayed in each row ( the image is the same for all rows, except using an array i am assigning it different values depending on the position). An xml file defines the relative layout that i am using. My problem is that i can either get the entire row to be clickable or nothing at all, I only want this image to be clickable, instead of the entire row. How would i be able to do this ? i am new to android and am pretty much following different tutorials trying to create my list. Any help would be appreciated.

layout is like this :

TEXT:

```
                     [Image]
```

TEXT:

thats wat a row looks like...getting two texts from two different arrays and shows it, a third array is used to link to the image. I just want this image to be clickable instead of the entire row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android's list component manages clicks per row. This makes it very difficult to achieve what you want to do. Two solutions come into mind:

1) If your list is never very long you could simply use linear layout and scroll view to build the list. This approach won't work if you fill in the list dynamically and you can't be sure that there won't be a very large number of rows as it would use too much memory in that case.

2) Other option is to use ListView but make your text components and images different view types in list ie. break you row into three. 
That can be achieved overriding list adapter's getItemViewType(int) 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)
In this approach you can make the image rows clickable but the text rows not.

Comment: thanks, i will try that .

I dont have a huge list, its only 8 elements at most that are shown.
its basically a daily view where it shows the time and class in one line, the second line shows the room number and building number and the image is a navigation button which when pressed takes you to google maps dropping a pin on the location. however it does switch between views, it loads data into an array from a database when you swipe left or right ( next or previous day ) clears the screen and shows the new daily view for that day. I tried using myClickhandler, it works for the button.....

Comment: ... i just dont know how to pass it the value for the position of the row in which the image was clicked. any clues as how to do that.
my function for that looks like 




public void myClickHandler(View v) 
    {   // displaying a toast to check for click
       // but dont know how to pass this the position of the row or how to find the position of the row.
}

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understand what you want to do but it sounds like you could solve your click listener problem by adding an anonymous inner class as listener for each of the buttons when you create them. That way each of the listener always knows in which row it is and handles the clicks correctly. Example of this concept can be found for example here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/anonymous_inner_classes.shtml

Comment: Thanks, I will try to follow your advice and try to implement it, if i get stuck ill try post a screen shot and a reference to my code so its easier to see what i am trying to do.
thanks a lot for your time and help.